# Build error when create a Titanium Module

Tags: android, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have create a new Mobile Module Project, but when i try to build it, i have this error:

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.2.GA\module\android\build.xml:165:
>   no executable specified

Did something wrong? I did the following step:
-Installed Appcelerator Studio
-It automatically installed Titanium SDK and i selected to install Android SDK
-Installed JAVA JDK
-Createed new module and tryed to build it

Comment: Looking at the file this is about `<apply executable="${toString:aidlexe}" failonerror="true">` and right before that line it echos te value of aidlexe. What is it? Is it existing on the system?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, edit the file:

C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.2.GA\module\android\build.xml

Or for any newer SDK versions, just use e.g. 5.3.1 instead of 5.2.2
On line 159, add ".exe" to aidl, like so:

TO

Comment: From <apply executable="${toString:aidlexe}" failonerror="true">
To: <apply executable="${toString:aidlexe}.exe" failonerror="true">

Answer (score 0):

To develop android module you will have to install some additional component and configure some path variables. There is a nice quick start guide where you will find everything. Thinks that need to install:

Android NDK

Ant

Eclipse Java Development Tools plugin

Android Development Tools plugin

gperf

Python

[Documentation Link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Quick+Start)