# Ant build failed for native Android modules in Titanium

Tags: windows, ant, android-ndk, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

My problems with Titanium Alloy on Windows 10 won't stop. I have created a new module with `ti create` and selecting `Module` and `android`. I added the path to `Android NDK` in the `build.properties` file. When trying to compile the module with `Ant`, I get the following error log:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\ekoppenhagen\workspace_titanium\Ti.NearbyMessages\android\build.xml
python.set.exec:
python.check:
     [echo] Testing for Python
     [exec] Python 3.5.2
init:
process.aidl:
     [echo] Generating java files from the .aidl files
     [echo] C:\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aidl.exe
process.annotations:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\ekoppenhagen\workspace_titanium\Ti.NearbyMessages\android\build\generated\json
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\ekoppenhagen\workspace_titanium\Ti.NearbyMessages\android\build\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Running Kroll binding generator.
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] No binding data found, creating new data file: org.appcelerator.titanium.bindings/Ti.NearbyMessages.json
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for proxy Example
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for module TiNearbyMessages
    [javac] C:\Users\ekoppenhagen\workspace_titanium\Ti.NearbyMessages\android\src\de\vater\solution\ti\nearbymessages\ExampleProxy.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.Log;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Log
    [javac]   location: package org.appcelerator.titanium.util
    [javac] C:\Users\ekoppenhagen\workspace_titanium\Ti.NearbyMessages\android\src\de\vater\solution\ti\nearbymessages\ExampleProxy.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConfig;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class TiConfig
    [javac]   location: package org.appcelerator.titanium.util
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Generating JSON: file:/C:/Users/ekoppenhagen/workspace_titanium/Ti.NearbyMessages/android/build/generated/json/org/appcelerator/titanium/bindings/Ti.NearbyMessages.json
    [javac] warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kroll.checkTiContext]'
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.1.0.v20160816022751\module\android\build.xml:185: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

Additionally to the normal setup (see [my other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608803/titanium-alloy-on-windows-10)), I have installed `Android NDK` (*v12.1.2977051*), `Ant` (*v1.9.7*), `Gperf` (*v3.0.1*), `Python` *32 bit* (*v3.5.2*), `Python Setup Tools` (*v25.2.0*) and all required `easy_install` packages listed on [the Appcelerator Docu](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Required_Python_Packages).

While installing these components, I met two several other problems:

1. The installation of the additional packages failed for various reasons. I had to install the `Visual C++ Build Tools` from [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).
2. Some files in the `Ti SDK` folder could not be found. I had to copy the content of `C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\<SDK version>\module\android\win32` to its parent's folder.

I modified my environment variables as follows:
*PATH:*
`C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Python35-32;C:\Python35-32\Scripts`
*ANDROID_NDK:*
`C:\android-sdk\ndk-bundle`

*(I also tested it for `Python` v2.x 32 Bit with the same results.)*

My first try to compile the `build.xml` located in my project's `android` folder failed with the following message:

```
    BUILD FAILED
    C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\<SDK version>\module\android\build.xml:165: no executable specified
```

Luckily, *Dan Kronholm* provided the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082190/build-error-when-create-a-titanium-module). But now I get the error mentioned at the beginning. I tried booth `Eclipse` *32 bit* and the `command line`.

Thank you for your help!

**TLDNR: my Ant build fails for my Titanium Alloy Android Module**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides problems with `Windows 10`, it looks like the used `Titanium SDK` has some missing files in the `\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\<SDK Version>\android\titanium.jar`. The files `Log.class` and `TiConfig.class` were some of them.

To "update" the `titanium.jar`, I used an older SDK and extracted its `titanium.jar`. Then, the missing files can be added via `Command Line` (look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html) for details).

Nonetheless, new errors appear... I think this forces me to switch to a MAC.